# Update firestore field from flutter with multiple documents

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: DB]

I want to update the isSeen field to 1, filtered by idTo messages in flutter code.

```
void onSeenMessages(){

    Stream<QuerySnapshot> messageRef = Firestore.instance
        .collection("messages")
        .document(groupChatId)
        .collection(groupChatId)
        .snapshots();

    messageRef. {
      field.documents. {
        productName.add(field.documents[index]["name"]);
      });
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! please edit your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need to change (isSeen) field:

You can do this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('messages').document(groupChatId).collection(groupChatId).document(documentID).updateData({
            'isSeen ': 1,
      });
```

witch documentID as in this image:

[image]

> If you don't know how to get documentID ? Please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes documentID is unknown and I need to check all the documents. here is the one I found and working fine now, let me know if this can be optimized.

```
void onSeenMessages() async{
    CollectionReference ref = Firestore.instance
        .collection('messages')
        .document(groupChatId)
        .collection(groupChatId);

    QuerySnapshot eventsQuery =  await ref.where('idTo', isEqualTo: id).where('isSeen', isEqualTo: 0).getDocuments();

    eventsQuery.documents.forEach((msgDoc) {
      msgDoc.reference.updateData({'isSeen': 1});
    });
  }
```